# Find all right inverses of matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

$A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 3 & 1 \end{array} \right)$

I understand that this is demands solving the system

$A_{2,3} \cdot x_{3,2} = I_{2,2}$

Which can be written as such:

$x_{11} - x_{21} = 1$

$x_{12} - x_{22} = 0$

$2 x_{11} + 3 x_{21} + x_{31} = 0$

$2 x_{12} + 3 x_{22} + x_{32} = 1$

And now I need to find the what all of the solutions are, this is where I need clarification. What is the next step in finding the solutions?

Sorry if the formatting is poor, I did my best, any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: You have here a system of four linear equations in six variables. Solving such things is often the _first_ thing one learns in linear algebra ... Does it confuse you that the variables have two subscripts instead of one? Ignore that; all that matters is that you have six different variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We wish to find all right inverses of 
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0\\2&3&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
To do so, note that
$$
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\
b_{21} & b_{22} \\
b_{31} & b_{32}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
satisfies $AB=I$ if and only if
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrcr}
b_{11} & + & b_{21} & & &&&&&&& = & 1 \\
&&&&&&b_{12} & + & b_{22} & & & = & 0 \\
2\,b_{11} & + & 3\,b_{21} & + & b_{31} &&&&&&& = & 0 \\
&&&&&&2\,b_{12} & + & 3\,b_{22} & + & b_{32} & = & 1
\end{array}
A quick row reduction then gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0&1&1&0&0\\2&3&1&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&2&3&1&1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-1&0&0&0&3\\0&1&1&0&0&0&-2\\0&0&0&1&0&-1&-1\\0&0&0&0&1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This means $AB=I$ if and only if
$$
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\
b_{21} & b_{22} \\
b_{31} & b_{32}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
3+b_{31} & -1+b_{32} \\
-2-b_{31} & 1-b_{32} \\
b_{31} & b_{32}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence all right inverses of $A$ are of the form
$$
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
+
x
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
+
y
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 \\
0 &1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for $x,y\in\Bbb R$.